# I found an arbitrary free, (free(<abitrary address>)), managed to locate a candidate address I wish to free, how do I proceed from here?

Tags: exploit, heap

While doing my first code auditing as a novice vulnerability resarchers I managed to stumble upon
my first free() in my target.
I managed to find a candiate location where I can control this value and thus trick my target to free any address.

Given I can turn this free() to an infoleak, how do I proceed from here with getting code execution?

Should I read Malloc-Demaleficarum and follow one of houses in order to trick malloc into returning my fake chunk? (i can call this free many times once i defeated ASLR).

Any hints and advice will be very welcome, I'm looking for the methodolodgy rather than a full step-by-step solution.

Comment: Look into a technique called House of Spirit. More details - https://github.com/shellphish/how2heap

Comment: thanks, i'll take a look into it.

Comment: how can i know the version of my malloc? it seem to be linked statically to my target binary and doesn't use the glibc one provided in my system.

Comment: Please add this in your post and someone will answer

Comment: I figured this out myself :)